# ArrayList with custom object how we can check whether an object in the list contain 1 value of data member isCorrect

Tags: java, android

I have an arraylist of custom object.

CustomObject:

```
public class CustomObject 
 {
private String name ;
private int isCorrcet ;
private int icon;
private int disableIcon;
}
```

For ArrayList having boolean Object we can check whether any boolean object exists having value true.

```
arrayList.contains(true);
```

how we can do this for custom object.check whether custom object exists whose data Member isCorrect having value `1`.

Comment: `contains()` depends on `equals()`, so you can only do so if you have `equals()` depend only on `isCorrect`, which probably isn't ideal for you.

Comment: when i use arrayList.contains(new CsustomObject()); the Custom object contain method work fine. but when i use arrayList.contains("Name"); CustomObject contain method does not work .can any body explain why.

Comment: Well, a `String` isn't a `CustomObject`. So of course `contains()` should return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Override Equals and hashCode. Here is an example

```
 public final class MethodName {
        private final String name;
        private final String mobile;

    public MethodName(String name, String mobile) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getMobile(){
        return mobile;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (object == null || object.getClass() != getClass()) {
      result = false;
    } else {
      MethodName method = (MethodName) object;
      if (this.name == method.getName()
          && this.mobile == mobile.getMobile()) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 7 * hash + this.name.hashCode();
    hash = 7 * hash + this.mobile.hashCode();
    return hash;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override and implement equals and hashcode method for your object.

You can find more details about it in the below post.
[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

contains() method works on the equals/hashcode implementation of the object. Basically it will iterate over the entire list passing each item of the list to the equals method of the object which you pass as a parameter to the 'contains' method.

Comment: `contains()` only depends on `equals()`. You can survive without `hashCode()`, although it isn't recommended to override one but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override equals and hashcode method in your custom object and then use contains on Arraylist.